# dynamically resizing images with css while maintaining correct scaling?

Tags: css, image-resizing

http://jsfiddle.net/CJzCA/

as you can see in the above jsfiddle the keyboard images are too big compared to the text, normally I would solve this by using photoshop but is there a way to resize the images (to scale) using css instead?

then it would be as simple as tweaking values in jsfiddler to resize images, then screenshot and crop the result for a fixed correct image size, would be a really useful time saver!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `background-size: contain;` to preserve the aspect ratio and keep the image inside the element:

```
.dbutton, .ctrlbutton {
    vertical-align: middle;

    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/CJzCA/2/**

Now, you can tweak the `width` and `height` individually and the image will always look good.

Answer (score 1):

Make an `img` inside each link for the image and simply change the width and height to your desired values in the css. This does not need CSS3.

Comment: all that does is crop a portion of the image, it also doesn't allow for proper scaling (retaining aspect ratio of original image)

Comment: +1 - This is what I would suggest. Having it as a background doesn't make sense.